# How to check if two types in different processes are identical in golang?

Tags: go, types, ipc

I am trying to write a system to help communication between processes written in golang. The other programmers are expected to provide two identical types to both processes while the system focusses on transporting data encoded by `encoding/gob`, yet it has to check for whether two types are identical or not in order to avoid human mistakes.

The thing is, is there any way in go that allows me to check whether the two types provided to either processes are exactly the same in each single field name and type, or do I need to figure one out myself?

Comment: If you have two values of interface type, e.g. `any`, you can use `reflect` to check if their *dynamic* types are identical.

Comment: @mkopriva But if I have two struct types in different processes, do I have any way to compare whether all their public fields have same names with same types?

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what you want. Are you looking for a runtime check that compares two different inputs? or are you looking for static analysis of a dev's source code to check that the code they've written satisfies your requirements? Are the two processes two separate programs? or are you talking about two functions running in the same program?

Comment: You need to be more clear, a lot more clear. Provide an example, can be pseudo-code for all I care, and explain how you expect this typecheck-between-two-unrelated-processes to function. How it's executed/triggered, what is its expected input, and what is its desired output.

Comment: Comparing fields' names, types, and order can be done at runtime with the `reflect` package and statically with the `go/ast` and co. packages.